# If/Else statement using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to do a survey and based on people's answers I want to return an answer. I am using PHP to use the If/Else statement, and I am very new to PHP. Since PHP is pretty similar to Javascript with the If/Else statements, besides the $ sign, I was attempted doing a function with a getelement.byid() inside of it, but seem to be getting a syntax error and can't figure out what that is. Here is the code:

```
<?php

function order()

{
if $doc->getElementById(ball) then 

    {print "you chose ball";
    }


}

?>
```

the error I get is in the *if $doc->getElementById(ball) then* line.
This is a PHP page on its own that is called from an HTML page. I'm sure it's something minor, but does anyone have an idea on what's missing/wrong with that line?

Comment: You should really learn language basics before asking such questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is just basic syntax. You don't have parentheses around the condition:

```
if (condition){
    //do something
}

if ($doc->getElementById(ball)){
    print "you chose ball";
}
```

Here's the [documentation on the if statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function order()
{
    if ($doc->getElementById(ball))
    {
        print "you chose ball";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't nearly as helpful as an answer that gives some context / explanation, and includes the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors with your code, I will list them in comments:

```
<?php

function order()

{
    // Missing opening/closing parentheses (); no "then" in php.
    if ($doc->getElementById(ball))
    // Where are you referencing $doc from? Unlike javascript, php does not have built-in DOM manipulation.    
    {print "you chose ball";
    }


}

?>
```